# Why does my dog get excited and go crazy when I touch the leash?

Tags: dogs, behavior, health, safety, exercise

Why does my dog get excited and go crazy when I touch the leash? My dog is a 2 year old french bull dog mix, however, he is generally lazy (sluggish or sleepy). However, the thing that makes him excited and go crazy is when I get his leash to take him for walks, but I am curious to know why. He'll pee, poop, vomit, hurt himself, or just go outright psycho in the house (3 lap sprints). I like to take him for walks but I never seen a dog go that crazy over a leash (I can't even get it on him most of the time).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't provide any insight beyond personal experience, but I have a small dog that goes absolutely nuts when he sees the leash come out from its hiding place.

The simple answer is the dog really, really, really wants to go on a walk with you.  Dogs are social animals, but they are also outdoor animals.  They like to be with their family but at the same time, they like to be outside, so when you put both together.... "outside with my family on a walk", that is really giving the dog everything they want/need.

Answer (score 0):

Our Boxers would act wild too (but no poop, pee or vomit), so I put out several leashes around the house and picked them up often so the dogs could see me, but ignored their antics even on days I took them for walks. I use halters for walks so I make them be calm enough to put the halter on or they didn't walk with me. After about a week they would sit down in front if me and wait for their halter. I cut a leash so it was about 6-8 inches long and the male dog wore the halter and leash around the house. I wouldn't walk a dog that acted that crazy.